# Scientfic Linux slate wiped clean on VM after restart

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, scientific-linux

I have installed `Scientific Linux` on VirtualBox. After every restart, I get this:

[image]

Which is fine, I suppose. But if I press a button, I get this:

[image]

I am not sure if that is a common occurrance, I am sure that it should boot right into the OS.

But when I got to create a user `useradd sampleUser` and provide it with a password `passwd sampleUser`, it works fine. But when I restart it, it doesn't save the users. I get this for an error:

```
[liveuser@livecd ~]$ su sampleUser
su: user sampleUser doesn't exist
```

Is there something I done wrong with this installation? I know that the user shouldn't be liveuser, but I installed this atleast 3 times already and can't seem get past this.

Comment: Check if the installation ISO image is still connected to the VM's virtual CD drive. You may be booting off of that.

Comment: Good thinking!! Post that as an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some distributions' installers don't eject the installation media when they're finished, so when you reboot you're booting from the installation media again.

I've gotten into the habit of always disconnecting the installation media from the VM's virtual CD drive after the first reboot after installation, because the next step is to install the guest additions, which will require use of the virtual CD drive.